# Check matches with 3's in a set of 6 numbers across 49 number draws

Tags: arrays, ruby, optimization, set, combinations

I am using `select` within Sidekiq:

```
require 'set'
require 'benchmark'

all_numbers = (1..49).to_a.combination(6)
needle = [1,2,3,4,5,6].to_set

Benchmark.bm do |x|
 x.report { all_numbers.select{|z| (needle & z).count == 3}  }
end

# user     system      total        real
# 74.200000   3.040000  77.240000 ( 78.901259)
```

I want to check thousands of such needles quickly. Is there a different way to find out this information? Is converting to C an option?

Note:
    all_numbers is a variable that does not change, and is as above always.
    Goal is to display all the sets which have 3 matches.
    Examples of needles can be got from:

```
(1..49).to_a.shuffle.first(6).sort
```

Comment: do the `all_numbers` input values change?

Comment: This number is mathematically calculable without looping, and fixed. Why would you run it more than once? (Also, the last `.to_a` is eating up both your memory and execution time needlessly)

Comment: Good spot on the unnecessary to_a. I want to see all the lines which have match 3 numbers, hence the current looping. I placed in an extra trailing count, which is confusing the question. Sorry

Comment: @VinnyGlennon, could you add a smaller example with the desired output?

Comment: @JosephWood that's not hard to do.  Just change `1..49` to something smaller like `1..19`

Comment: Can you explain HOW `needle` might change? Give examples. Also is `all_numbers` exactly what you have here?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Examples of needles can be got from (1..49).to_a.shuffle.first(6).sort

Comment: @VinnyGlennon it sounds then like this is finite data. If so, can't you just pre-calculate it all and store it as a data structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of `needle` is members of `all_numbers`:

For three to be correct, that's a 3-combination of 6:

```
(6*5*4) / (1*2*3) = 20
```

For the remaining three to be incorrect, that's a 3-combination of the remaining (49-6):

```
(43*42*41) / (1*2*3) = 12341
```

Thus, the total number of combinations is

```
12341 * 20 = 246820
```

In code:

```
require 'benchmark'

size_all = 49
size_needle = 6
required = 3

def binomial(n, k)
  ((n - k + 1)..n).inject(&:*) / (1..k).inject(&:*)
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report {
    binomial(size_needle, required) * binomial(size_all - size_needle, required)
  }
end

#        user     system      total        real
#   0.000026   0.000006   0.000032 (  0.000030)
```

Slightly faster.

EDIT: After the requirements are changed:

```
class Array
  def semimatching_combination(needle, num_total, num_needle)
    unless block_given?
      return to_enum(__method__, needle, num_total, num_needle) do
        binomial(needle.size, num_needle) *
          binomial(self.size - needle.size, num_total - num_needle)
      end
    end

    needle.combination(num_needle) do |needle_comb|
      (self - needle).combination(num_total - num_needle) do |other_comb|
        yield (needle_comb + other_comb).sort
      end
    end
  end
end

(1..49).to_a.semimatching_combination((1..6).to_a, 6, 3).size
# => 246820
(1..49).to_a.semimatching_combination((1..6).to_a, 6, 3).to_a
# => [[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], ...]
```

You can replace `sort` with `to_set` (with `require 'set'`) if you want, depending on what you want to generate.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. Goal is to find the matching sets, rather than count of sets, hence why I have to loop over millions of records, hence the requirment to optimise it. My bad in causing confusion with my question.

Comment: @VinnyGlennon see updated answer... this is blazing! Nice one!